# Displaying order ID as a UNIQUE string type in woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

Ok I want to display the latest Order id as a unique string without the #

I have used this code to attempt to display on checkout page but it displays nothing.

```
<?php print $order->get_id();?>
```

Also i would like a function that allows the place order button on the checkout page to run my custom gateway when its pressed currently I am doing this using html.

Comment: In checkout page, the order ID doesn't exist yet… Only in "Order received" page (thankyou page).

Answer (score 0):

If i'm understanding correctly your function get_id() is returning something like "#1234";

In this case you could just do a str_replace(). For example:

`$id = "#1234";`

`$id = (int) str_replace("#", "", $id);`

If not, please edit your question.

Comment: @BarkerAntony
May you can post some code of your get_id() function? It would help me a lot.

Comment: Or you just do

<?php print(str_replace("#", "", $order->get_id()); ?>

Comment: public function get_order_id( $context = 'view' ) {
        return $this->get_prop( 'order_id', $context );
    }

Comment: Oh, im sorry. I forgot a ) at the end. It must look like ...get_id()));

Comment: thx is  there any way i can do using the global $woocommerce way

Comment: I'm very sorry I can't help you with this particular framework. But I hope I could help you anyway.